# Is there a JSON schema for the Whatsapp Business API?

Tags: java, jsonschema, whatsapp

I'm playing with the Whatsapp Business Api and to make things more organized/reliable I would like to generate some Java code based off some kind of JSON Schema for this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference

Are there any schemas out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any external resources but there are no complete JSON schemas in the WhatsApp Business API documentation, you can prepare it by copying the field properties or part of the sample JSON from the documentation,

Second, you can use [WhatsApp Business API Postman Collections](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/postman), which might help you.